# Appdynamics configuration to detect Java Elasticsearch client calls

Tags: java, elasticsearch, appdynamics

I am trying to find suitable entry point for ES client. At the moment I have:

Class that implements an Interface which equals org.elasticsearch.client.ElasticsearchClient

and method name: prepareSearch

It seems to collect number of calls but I wonder if there is a better configuration to make ES calls to show up in Tier Flow Map.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask support on this if you can't get it to work. Here is the configuration for custom exit and entry points in the product: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO14S/Configure+Custom+Exit+Points